# jscodeshift - How to insert a call expression at the beginning of a blockstatement

Tags: javascript, jscodeshift

I'm playing around with ASTs. My goal for now is to add a an identifier to every block statement in the file. But ast explorer is throwing an error that I cannot decipher.

```
function foo() {
   console.log('bar');
}
```

after mod

```
function foo() {
   baz
   console.log('bar');
}
```

[AST](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/67b195609bd8820eb571e873d46ae920/e5a315b62a6152c3ff56270e56bab5f0656f8a6e)

How does one go about adding a such thing with jscodeshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to be aware of

- A block statement consists of an array of statements. You want to prepend to that array.
- You cannot insert a bare expression (e.g. an identifier) into that array. You actually have to create an `ExpressionStatement`.

The following would work:

```
root
  .find(j.BlockStatement)
  .forEach((path) => {
    path.get('body').value.unshift(j.expressionStatement(j.identifier('bar')));
  });
```